# Can you customize what contributors see on your Github project Issues tab?

Tags: github, open-source

There are some things, I would like to customize for my Github projects or for projects I contribute to. There's quite a bit you can do by editing the description of the project, adding CONTRIBUTING.md, adding Issue templates etc.

In this question I would like to focus mainly on **what contributors see in the Issues tab.**

[image: Image 1: Hint shown on Issue tab of symfony project]

<sup>*Image 1: Hint shown on Issue tab of symfony project*</sup>

I have seen variations in the hint message that Github displays on the Issue tab (for new contributors) and I am not aware of any way to configure this.

1. Can you configure it?
2. Why does Github sometimes only mention "help wanted" labels and sometimes "help wanted" or "good first issue" labels?

What I do know, is you only see this message as new contributor.

What I am guessing about suggesting only "help wanted" or "help wanted" and "good first issue": the latter might be displayed, **if** label "good first issue" exists **and** there are open issues with this label. It would be nice to not have to guess about this and I can't find this answer in help.github.com.

[image: Image 2: Hint shown on Issue tab of symfony-docs project]

<sup>*Image 2: Hint shown on Issue tab of symfony-docs project*</sup>

See also: [Github Help: Helping new contributors find your project with labels](https://help.github.com/articles/helping-new-contributors-find-your-project-with-labels/)